# ERROR CODE 1215 - Você não pode add a chave estrangeira

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, modelagem, back-end

Tabela 1: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tabela 2: [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comando: `ALTER TABLE extras ADD FOREIGN KEY (login) REFERENCES usuario(login);`

Resposta: `Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint`

> Não é possível encontrar um índice na tabela referenciada onde as
>   colunas referenciadas aparecem como as primeiras colunas, ou os tipos
>   de coluna na tabela e a tabela referenciada não correspondem à
>   restrição. Observe que o tipo de armazenamento interno de ENUM e SET
>   mudou em

Não consigo identificar o motivo do erro. Alguém pode me ajudar?

Ps. como podem ver, os dois campos estão com o mesmo tipo ( varchar (15) )

Desde ja obrigado

Comment: Qual SGBD você está usando?

Comment: estou usando o Mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aparentemente está certo sua estrutura, verifique se o tipo de tabela está como InnoDB mesmo, elas podem estar como MyISAM o que não permite criação de FK, segue script que criei à partir do seu print e funcionou normalmente:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `usuario` (
  `login` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
  `senha` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`login`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `extras` (
  `idFunc` INT NULL,
  `login` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  `data` DATETIME NULL,
  `extra` TEXT NULL,
  INDEX `fk_extras_usuario_idx` (`login` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_extras_usuario`
    FOREIGN KEY (`login`)
    REFERENCES `usuario` (`login`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: As duas estão criadas como InnoDB.

Comment: Tentou rodar o script que postei?

Comment: Eu refiz as tabelas e deu certo. Geralmente gosto de tentar entender o erro, mas como estava sem tempo optei pela solução mais ágil